# GUI to get user inputs and pass them to a batch file

Tags: javascript, user-interface, batch-file, vbscript, hta

I have a batch file that runs a SQL query according to user inputs. I want to make a very simple GUI to take user inputs and pass those inputs to the batch file. The GUI is for the users who are afraid to work with the black CMD window. My knowledge in HTA, JavaScript and VBscript is limited but I am sure it's someting that I can learn if someone guided me to the right direcrion.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like this (save it as `.bat`) ?

```
<!-- :
:: textSubmitter.bat
@echo off
for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%p in ('mshta.exe "%~f0"') do (
    set "text=%%p"
)

echo your text is %text%
pause
exit /b
-->

<html>
<head><title>text submitter</title></head>
<body>

    <script language='javascript' >
        function pipeText() {
            var pass=document.getElementById('pass').value;
            var fso= new ActiveXObject('Scripting.FileSystemObject').GetStandardStream(1);
            close(fso.Write(pass));

        }
    </script>

    <input type='text' name='pass' size='15'></input>
    <hr>
    <button onclick='pipeText()'>Submit</button>

</body>
</html>
```

I don't think here's the place for hta/html tutorials but you can use this hybrid technique to advance with your task.

Comment: Nice!... The UI is a little limited (but I *completely* get that this was just a framework / PoC and could be polished if the user wants further with some styles, css, etc), but as far as "single-file, self-contained solution" this is awesome!... 20 lines of code, no external files that risk being moved/deleted, no external dependencies that the user may not have installed -- thanks for sharing, I might look at adopting this kind of framework for some of my current cmd/bat scripts! 